# Headless Browser (Chrome)maximize issue on jenkins, using cucumber watir

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, watir, headless-browser

I am facing the issue that while executing my test script on jenkin machine the headless browser is not maximizing but on my local machine it is working fine.First it was failing on local as well but after using the code :

```
Before do |scenario|
  DataMagic.load_for_scenario(scenario)
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless:true
  screen_width = @browser.execute_script("return screen.width;")
  screen_height = @browser.execute_script("return screen.height;")
  @browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(screen_width,screen_height)
  @browser.driver.manage.window.move_to(0,0)
end
```

but after using this it worked on local and failed on local. So guys please let me know resolution for the same.
Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "browser is not maximizing"? Is there an exception? If you get the browser size, did it change?

Comment: It's likely that your Jenkins machine has a lower screen resolution, so maximizing it on there would look different than maximizing it locally. Consider taking a screenshot at the point of failure to see what the problem actually is.

Comment: We are running the setup on a server so not able to amend the resolution.  It's running in headless mode.

Comment: Have you tried some debugging output?  What values are being returned for screen height and screen width?
In my experience you are better off just to set the browser to the minimum supported screen size for the app you are developing. Eg 1024x768 (if an old iPad is smallest expected screen.  or if you expect all users to have HD displays then 1920x1080.